# HTTPS to HTTPS redirect session issue

Tags: session, cakephp, https, redirect

I have a site (built on LAMP (cakephp) and has ssl certificate installed) which has a secure payment page. After filling up necessary information user proceeds to a payment gateway page. After all the process at the gateway end, gateway redirects to one of my URL, which I have to mention with a payment request. 
Now when I keep this url as http redirect happens properly and all the sessions are maintained. But I want to make this page as https, and when the payment gateway redirects to the https version of the URL, my session information dies and I get redirected to my home page.

eg: my payment page
https://www.mysite.com/payment

from here user goes to the payment gateway site, does necessary things and payment gateway redirects it to

http://www.mysite.com/paymentResponse (this url i have to mention in the request)

now i have to make this as HTTPS, but when I do that my session info dies

Plz help me

Thanks,
Dinesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it supposedly works for plain HTTP requests, but the problem may be related to `Configure::write('Security.level')` being set to `medium` or `high`, which activates PHP's `session.referer_check`, which may be the reason sessions are dying for you when being redirected from external sites.

Comment: Thnx a lot for your help and promptness, the solution worked for me. But I still am puzzled, why it worked for HTTP requests earlier.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the solution was here. Is it to set Security.level to 'low' or can we keep it at medium and set session.referer_check to 0 in our core.php?

Comment: Any chance of expanding this answer? I too am loosing my session after Auth in https and redirecting back to http.