# Cake session getting lost on return from payment gateway

Tags: cakephp

In my app, I have a session which persists when the user moves from page to page. However, the app uses a payment gateway and if the user goes to the payment gateway and then presses back to try to return to my app Cake is dropping the old session (and all the data it contained) and making a new one.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989946/https-to-https-redirect-session-issue) which is kinda the same issue, except it's happening when the user presses "back" from the payment gateway which I didn't really think would be classed as being referred.

Anyway, the advice in that question is to change `Configure::write('Security.level')` to `low` but I'm using CakePHP 2.3 and I notice from the [changelog](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/lorenzo/2013/01/28/cakephp_2_3_0_is_out) that one of the things that has been done is "Removed Security.level from core.php" -- and this seems to be because this particular setting is no longer used for anything.

So, my question is how do I disable whatever it is that is causing Cake to drop and regenerate the session when a user is either referred (or simply presses back) from a payment gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest changing the following `core.php` settings:

```
Configure::write('Session', 
    array(
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'timeout' => '30',
        'autoRegenerate' => false
    )
);
```

I had a similar issue and that solved it for me.

Thanks,

Comment: strange, it seemed like it worked for a bit and then it stopped working again. Now I've also had to add `'checkAgent' => false` to make it work again. I don't understand why pressing "back" from the payment gateway would change the user agent, though. It doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

IE with chormeframe has a habit of sending first request to a "different" site with plain IE-useragent header whereas subsequent contains "chromeframe " in it. On a non-Cake site I had same issue with sessions when checking useragent.